# An elementary functional inequality

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis, inequalities

Let $g$ be a $C^1$ function with $g(0)=0$ and $g(t)>0$ for all $t>0$. I am surprised that for all such $g$ the following seems to hold

$\frac{\int_0^t(g'(s))^2ds}{g^2(t)}\geq \frac{1}{t}$  for all t>0.

I tried to find a counterexample but I was not successful. Is the above true or one can find a counterexample?

Comment: $(tg'-g)^2\ge0$

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev, do you mean $(t g'(s) - g(t))^2 \ge 0$?

Comment: No, I think everything is at $t$. Just multiply everything by $g^2$ and differentiate, observing that the inequality holds at $t=0$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well since $g(0) = 0$, we may rewrite the desired inequality as:

$$\left(\int_0^{t} 1\,ds\right)\left(\int_0^{t} (g'(s))^2\,ds\right) \ge \left(\int_0^t g'(s)\,ds\right)^2$$

which is just the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality.